# How to make a programmatically added view size to its parent view?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, interface-builder, uistackview

I am working on a custom keyboard with its own view that I edit in the Interface Builder.

The view is added programmatically to the keyboard root view on load. It contains stack views and is filling the whole view, sizing automatically.

The issue is the keyboard view doesn't size to the view of the app it opens in. Seems like it has some fixed size because when I rotate the simulator horizontally, I can see more in width, and less when vertical.

How do I make it size to the width of the root view it's placed in?

Here is how the keyboard looks in the Interface Builder and in a Simulator running iPhone 5S:

[image: sizes]

Comment: Please add some screenshot to show how it is looking right now.

Answer (score 0):

First we need to get a hook into size changes from layout changes, we could do this like so:

```
override var bounds: CGRect {
    didSet {
      print("Bounds have changed: \(bounds)")
    }
}
```

This should be used in your custom keyboard view. Next we want to update the custom keyboard layout. Looking at your screenshots it suggests that all we would need to do is adjust the height and width of the keys, later on you could  add adjustments due size class changes, giving more control of the layout. You will need to keep a reference to the height and width constraint using `@IBOutlets` or by iterating through your subviews and manually finding and altering the width and height constraints, both can be tedious, but using the `@IBOutlets` is easier.

```
func updateKeys() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // Create array of width constraints
        let widthConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = widthArray() 
        widthConstraints.forEach { _ in /* change width constant for current layout */ }

        // Create array of height constraints
        let heightConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = heightArray() 
        heightConstraints.forEach { _ in /* change height constant for current layout */ }

    }
}
```

This is just one way of doing, I find that with auto layout there's always one that one way of doing it with complex layouts, but it should show you a pattern you can use.

Answer (score -2):

Did you try implementing these notifications?

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                       selector:@selector(keyboardFrameWillChange:)
                                           name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                         object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                       selector:@selector(keyboardFrameWillChange:)
                                           name:UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification
                                         object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                           name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                         object:nil];
```

Then when these notifications are called, resize your view to the keyboard frame

```
CGRect keyboardFrame;
[[notification.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] getValue:&keyboardFrame];

CGRect viewFrame = keyboardFrame;
```

Comment: This question is tagged Swift, not Objective-C.